# Как гугл реагирует на редирект со стороны seo?

Tags: php, seo

У меня есть мультиязычный сайт и мне нужно что бы при заходе на домен меня перекидывало на определенную языковую версию, а именно с `https://mydomen.com` на `https://mydomen.com/uk-ua/about`.

Я делаю проверку в роутере моего сайта на пустой запрос(`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) и делаю редирект - `header("Location: https://mydomen.com/uk-ua/about")`.

Как со стороны СЕО гугл будет реагировать на данную операцию? Плохо ли это для продвижения сайта или это правильно в данном случае?

Примером данной ситуации является сайт https://docs.microsoft.com

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=ru - по моему достаточно понятно написано. 
Первый результат в выдаче "google language redirect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Плохо ли это для продвижения сайта или это правильно в данном случае?

**Это плохо и не делайте это**. Для примера рассмотрите такую ситуацию: немецкоговорящий пользователь, который находится в командировке или на отдыхе в России, с вашим перенаправление будет получать только версию вашего веб-сайта на русском языке. Скорее всего он уйдет с вашего вебсайта и вы потеряете потенциального целевого пользователя.

Кроме того, гуглбот имеет IP США (возможно, также в западной Европе), поэтому он будет перенаправляться вами только на анлийскую версию (если она есть) или на версию языка страны расположения гуглбота. Русская версия может быть недоступна для гуглбот и эта версия может быть не индексирована.

Проверьте следующую информацию из отличного **[Руководства по международному расширению веб-сайтов: Hreflang, ccTLD и многое другое! от Moz](https://moz.com/blog/guide-to-international-seo)**:

> **Обнаружение языков** Многие компании хотят сделать работу с сайтом максимально удобной для пользователя. Они пытаются определить
>   предпочтения пользователя без необходимости ввода данных от
>   пользователя. Это может вызвать проблемы с языками.
>
> Есть несколько способов определить языковые предпочтения пользователя.
>   Наиболее используемыми являются настройки браузера и IP-адрес. Не
>   рекомендуется использовать IP-адрес для определения языка. IP-адрес
>   может показывать приблизительное местоположение пользователя, но не
>   его предпочтительный язык. IP-адрес также очень неточный. **Следует
>   избегать любых автоматических перенаправлений на основе IP**.

Фокусируйте ваше внимание на руководстве Гугл, которое указал в комментарии ***Shevtsov Eugene***. В этом случае это будет дружественно для Гугл и для вашего веб-сайта.

Comment: Поэтому нужно редиректить не по IP, а по Accept-Language. Тогда немца отредиректит на немецкую версию даже в России. Ну а для гугла прописать hreflang/Sitemap

Answer (score -2):

Если посмотреть в гугле (site:docs.microsoft.com/en-us) то видно что гугл распознаёт без проблем. Но при этом ваш сайт должен быть подстроен под docs.microsoft.com/en-us но лучше для мультиязычности используйте сессии.
Пример этого rustpay.com

Comment: Никогда не используйте сессии для переключения языков. Гугл не одобрит как и пользователь